# disable group of inputs if another input group has data entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-deployment

I am systematically trying to give my app a way to disable and enable groups of inputs based on whether on of the groups of inputs has anything entered.  I started playing around with how to do this in jFiddle, but I am currently stuck.

Problem is I am having trouble getting it to work on multiple groups.. works fine on one group.

Here is my jFiddle and Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3t5RL/5/

```
<div class="one_or_other">
    <h1>Some Input Group</h1>
    <p class="ooo_group_1">
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_2","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_2","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
    </p>
    OR
    <p class="ooo_group_2">
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
    </p>
    OR
    <p class="ooo_group_3">
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_2"]' /> 
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_2"]' /> 
    </p>
</div>

<div class="one_or_other">
    <h1>Some Other Input Group</h1>
    <p class="ooo_group_1">
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_2","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_2","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
    </p>
    OR
    <p class="ooo_group_2">
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_3"]' /> 
    </p>
    OR
    <p class="ooo_group_3">
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_2"]' /> 
        <input type="text" data-disable='["ooo_group_1","ooo_group_2"]' /> 
    </p>
</div>
```

AND

```
$('.one_or_other').each(function() {

    block = $(this);    
    block.find('input').keyup( function() {       
        if(this.value.length !== 0) {
            json = $(this).data('disable');
            $.each(json, function(i,item) {
                block.find('.' + item + ' input').prop('disabled',true).addClass('disabled');
            });
        } else {
            block.find('input').prop('disabled',false).removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jVAeU/) is what you want.

```
$('.one_or_other').on('keyup', 'input', function () {
    var selector = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    $('p[class="' + selector + '"] input').attr('disabled', false);
    $('p[class!="' + selector + '"] input').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Or, if you want to keep more fine grained control, you can just act on the block's [parent](http://jsfiddle.net/AMpbs/).

Comment: unfortunately this wont work. if you enter something in the first group.. it disabled things in the second group also.

Comment: That sounds like what you want.

"Problem is I am having trouble getting it to work on multiple groups.. works fine on one group."

What are you looking for?

Comment: when i have a separate group of inputs, clearing an input in an unrelevant group should not clear the disables on other groups.  i think i am just not explaining myself right :(

Answer (score 0):

I played around for a bit and decided to create a jquery plugin out of it which seems to handle my quesiton:

http://jsfiddle.net/8pyF2/9/

I did add the ability for it to also work with selects and also added a clear button.  Let me know if this should be refactorred.

**html:**

```
<div class="grouped_choice">
     <h1>Some Input Group</h1>
    <p>
        <input type="text" rel="group_1" />
        <input type="text" rel="group_1" />
        <a href="#" class="clear_group" rel="group_1">clear</a>
    </p>OR
    <p>
        <input type="text" rel="group_2" />
        <input type="text" rel="group_2" />
        <a href="#" class="clear_group" rel="group_2">clear</a>
    </p>OR
    <p>
        <input type="text" rel="group_3" />
        <input type="text" rel="group_3" />
        <a href="#" class="clear_group" rel="group_3">clear</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="grouped_choice">
     <h1>Some Other Input Group</h1>
    <p>
        <input type="text" rel="group_1" />
        <input type="text" rel="group_1" />
        <a href="#" class="clear_group" rel="group_1">clear</a>
    </p>OR
    <p>
        <input type="text" rel="group_2" />
        <input type="text" rel="group_2" />
        <a href="#" class="clear_group" rel="group_2">clear</a>
    </p>OR
    <p>
        <input type="text" rel="group_3" />
        <input type="text" rel="group_3" />
        <a href="#" class="clear_group" rel="group_3">clear</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.groupedChoice = function () {
        this.each(function () {

            var parent = $(this);

            // handle change
            parent.on('change', 'input,select', function () {

                var field, group;

                field = $(this);
                group = field.attr('rel');

                if (field.val().length !== 0) {
                    parent.find('input[rel!="' + group + '"],select[rel!="' + group + '"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    var empty = true
                    parent.find('input[rel='+group+'],input[rel='+group+']').each( function() {                        
                        if($(this).val().length !== 0) empty = false
                    });
                    if(empty) parent.find('input,select').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
                }

            });

            // handle group clear
            parent.find('.clear_group').click( function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();    
                group = $(this).attr('rel');  
                disabled = false;
                parent.find('input[rel='+group+'],select[rel='+group+']').each( function() {
                    if( $(this).prop('disabled') ) disabled = true
                }) 
                if(!disabled) {
                    parent.find('input[rel='+group+'],select[rel='+group+']').val('');
                    parent.find('input,select').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
                }
            });
        });

    };
})(jQuery);

$('.grouped_choice').groupedChoice();
```